# From Azure synapse read/write from/to an Azure data lake

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake

I am trying to write a pyspark dataframe to a the data lake. This is the code I have:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type", "com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.LinkedServiceBasedTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set(f"spark.storage.synapse.{source_full_storage_account_name}.linkedServiceName", linked_service)
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(f"spark.storage.synapse.{source_full_storage_account_name}.linkedServiceName", linked_service)
spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("spark.storage.synapse.linkedServiceName", "LS_abs_idodatalakedev")

adls_path = f"abfs://{container}@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/"
file = adls_path + file_location
spark.read.format('csv').load(file)
```

Results in the following error:

> ```
> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In [53], line 7
>   5 adls_path = f"abfs://{container}@{storage_account}.dfs.core.windows.net/"
>   6 file = adls_path + file_location
> ```
>
> ----> 7 spark.read.format('csv').load(file)
>
> File /opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:177,
> in DataFrameReader.load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
> 175 self.options(**options)
> 176 if isinstance(path, str):
> --> 177     return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
> 178 elif path is not None:
> 179     if type(path) != list:
>
> File
> ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.**call**(self, *args)    1315 command =
> proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\    1316     self.command_header +\    1317
> args_command +\    1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART    1320 answer =
> self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
> -> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(    1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1324 for temp_arg
> in temp_args:    1325     temp_arg._detach()
>
> File /opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py:190, in
> capture_sql_exception..deco(*a, **kw)
> 188 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
> 189     try:
> --> 190         return f(*a, **kw)
> 191     except Py4JJavaError as e:
> 192         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
>
> File
> ~/cluster-env/clonedenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py:326,
> in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
> 324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
> 325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
> --> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
> 327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
> 328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
> 329 else:
> 330     raise Py4JError(
> 331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
> 332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4037.load. : Status
> code: -1 error code: null error message: Auth failure: HTTP Error
> -1CustomTokenProvider getAccessToken threw org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.contracts.exceptions.KeyProviderException
> : No LinkedServiceName provided in configuration. Please set
> spark.storage.synapse.linkedServiceNameorg.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.AzureADAuthenticator$HttpException:
> HTTP Error -1CustomTokenProvider getAccessToken threw
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.contracts.exceptions.KeyProviderException
> : **No LinkedServiceName provided** in configuration. Please set
> spark.storage.synapse.linkedServiceName   at
> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.executeHttpOperation(AbfsRestOperation.java:274)
> ...

The error raises the point that no linkedservicename is set. However, when I run:

```
spark.conf.get(f"spark.storage.synapse.{source_full_storage_account_name}.linkedServiceName")
```

I get the linkedservice name I provided earlier.

Also when I run:

```
spark.sparkContext.getConf().get(f"spark.storage.synapse.{source_full_storage_account_name}.linkedServiceName")
```

I get nothing.

Is the linkedservicename not rightly set?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can use a linked service for reading data.

1. When the linked service authentication method is set to **Account Key**, use the **SAS** key by specifying the provider as **LinkedServiceBasedSASProvider**.

```py
%%pyspark
# Set the required configs
source_full_storage_account_name = "teststorage.dfs.core.windows.net"
spark.conf.set(f"spark.storage.synapse.{source_full_storage_account_name}.linkedServiceName", "<LINKED SERVICE NAME>")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(f"fs.azure.account.auth.type.{source_full_storage_account_name}", "SAS")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(f"fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.{source_full_storage_account_name}", "com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.LinkedServiceBasedSASProvider")

# Python code
df = spark.read.csv('abfss://<CONTAINER>@<ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows.net/<DIRECTORY PATH>')

df.show()
```

2. If the linked service authentication method is set to **Managed Identity** or **Service Principal**, the linked service will use the Managed Identity or Service Principal token with the **LinkedServiceBasedTokenProvider** provider.

```py
%%pyspark
# Python code
source_full_storage_account_name = "teststorage.dfs.core.windows.net"
spark.conf.set(f"spark.storage.synapse.{source_full_storage_account_name}.linkedServiceName", "<LINKED SERVICE NAME>")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(f"fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.{source_full_storage_account_name}", "com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.LinkedServiceBasedTokenProvider")

df = spark.read.csv('abfss://<CONTAINER>@<ACCOUNT>.dfs.core.windows.net/<DIRECTORY PATH>')

df.show()
```

The error occurs because the linked service name is not configured properly.

Stop your current session and re-run your notebook cells with one of the above codes according to your linked service configuration.

Also, ensure that you have provided the correct linked service name.

[image]

Creating a new session removes all current configuration, and re-running the code configures the authentication values correctly.

Output:

[image]